# How do I use a batch file to convert directory name to one with backslashes before spaces for use in linux shell

Tags: windows, batch, android, syntax, adb

I am writing a batch script in windows 10 to move files from a specific folder on my android phone to my computer and then delete the files on my phone. I would like to only have to define only one variable for the directory on my phone. The problem is that I am using a windows command to copy the files (%phonedir%) and a shell command (%phonedirsh) within android to delete the files and both commands have a different syntax for dealing with spaces in directory names.

Is there anyway I can us one variable for the directory and then have the script automatically convert it to the proper syntax for each command?

This is my current code:

```
@echo off
:: SET VARIABLES
set "adb=C:\ADB"
set "phone=192.168.1.102"
set "compdir=E:\<USER>\Desktop"
set "phonedir=/sdcard/android/data/psyberia.alpinequest.full/files/landmarks/"exported landmarks"/"
set "phonedirsh=/sdcard/android/data/psyberia.alpinequest.full/files/landmarks/exported\ landmarks/"
:: ESTABLISH WIRELESS CONNECTION
%adb%\adb.exe connect %phone%:5555
%adb%\adb.exe devices
:: COPY FILES USING ADB
%adb%\adb.exe pull %phonedir% %compdir%
:: DELETE FILES ON PHONE USING SHELL
%adb%\adb.exe shell rm %phonedirsh%*
:: CLOSE WIRELESS CONNECTION
%adb%\adb.exe kill-server
pause
```

I am pretty new to this.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should be able to use the `%phonedir%` variable AS IS for both.  If not.. Try removing the outer quotes for the set command and leave them around  `exported landmarks`.  You don't NEED to quote the entire "SET" commands (although it is a good practice).  This also means that you need to be CAREFUL that your variables don't have a space at the end of the line.  Try again. This should be a valid path for Linux.. if it doesn't work, it's adb's or rm's fault.  Try shelling into the device and play with the paths from there to get it right.

Comment: You have other options too.  Quote the ENTIRE PATH.. if you really want to escape the space with "\ ", you would do that like this:  %phonedir: =\ % <- this says replace space with backslash+space.